# adding hops during second fermentation

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I am just a beginner, only having my first batch currently in primary fermentation. Reading the directions that came with my kit it tells me in one step to do a second fermentation  for 2 to 4 weeks. While the next step is adding hops 1-2 weeks before bottling day. My question is if I ferment for 4 weeks then do I put the hops in during  week 2? Or do I ferment for 4 weeks then do 2 additional weeks adding the hops? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: What style of beer is it?  IPA?  Pale Ale?  Saison?

Comment: It is a PA that I am brewing up.

Answer (score 1):

It would mean adding the hops at 2 weeks into your secondary; if your secondary is 4 weeks long and you want it to sit on dry-hops for 2 weeks, then add them at 2 weeks before you bottle.

Incidentally, I'll note that most commercial brewers only dry hop for a handful of days, not weeks.  And "secondary" is generally useless on this sort of timeframe. You can probably get away with doing a 2-week primary, adding the dry hops a 3-5 days before you rack out of the primary vessel.

Comment: As frequently happens, what commercial brewers do may or may not have a bearing on homebrewing.  I almost always add dry hops to a keg of beer in the serving fridge and they stay in for months without problems.  Many other homebrewers do the same.  Don't ignore what commercial brewers are doing, but make your own decisions based on experience.

Comment: Denny, are you serving with hops in the keg?  Perhaps for me it's just the first pour or two, but I get a harsh vegetal bite until I remove the hops (as well as pour off a glass or two).